# Play (seen in the late 1980s to the early 1990s) about a group of teenagers in a haunted house. One gets the head of a pig due to a ham sandwich

Tags: story-identification, theater-play, haunted-house

I could have sworn I posted about this here, but I can find no reference to having done so. Somewhere in the late 1980s to the early 1990s (I remember being a fairly young child), my family went to an outdoor theater and watched a show involving a group of teenagers (maybe young adults) who visit a house that turns out to be haunted. I want to say there were 4-5 of them, and at least one male and one female in the group. A series of largely unrelated scenes have stuck in my head.

- Early in the show, they walk into a room and a rocking chair starts rocking on its own. I think one or more of the teenagers went over and stopped it, but when they walked away, it started rocking again
- Later (I think next to the rocking chair), one of the teenagers gets sucked into the floor (trap door) and smoke billowed out of it. It must have been near intermission because I remember getting to walk up and see the trap door, and the smoke (dry ice?) was still wisping out of it
- At one point, one of the teenagers decides to eat a ham sandwich that they found, and later turned up with a pig's head with someone screaming that "You are what you eat!"

I don't remember how it ended. I don't know if it was a licensed play, an adaptation of another piece of fiction, or an original play. My memory is that the supernatural was real in the context of the show, and at least one of the teenagers might not have made it out at the end. Looking back on it, I suspect it was a college production.

I just consulted with my mother, and she neither remembers the play nor the outdoor theater we might have gone to. I'm pretty sure that it was in Kentucky, Ohio, or West Virginia, within a few hours travel from Ashland, KY where I was living at the time.